# How to filter json object from some objects. (Select only some values)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need a help! I have a json object like this:
(res.json(record[0].content))
I need to transform this json to another view... Select only some values... I would be grateful for any help!

```
[
    {
        "classId": 0,
        "type": "d",
        "cluster": -2,
        "position": 1,
        "version": 0,
        "value": {
            "@type": "d",
            "rid": "#15:0",
            "class": "Currency",
            "Name_currency": "Фунт"
        }
    },
    {
        "classId": 0,
        "type": "d",
        "cluster": -2,
        "position": 2,
        "version": 0,
        "value": {
            "@type": "d",
            "rid": "#15:1",
            "class": "Currency",
            "Name_currency": "Доллар"
        }
    },
    {
        "classId": 0,
        "type": "d",
        "cluster": -2,
        "position": 3,
        "version": 0,
        "value": {
            "@type": "d",
            "rid": "#15:2",
            "class": "Currency",
            "Name_currency": "Гривна"
        }
    }
]
```

How can I get this? Only values of my json object?

```
[
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "rid": "#15:0",
        "class": "Currency",
        "Name_currency": "Фунт"\
    },
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "rid": "#15:1",
        "class": "Currency",
        "Name_currency": "Доллар"
    },
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "rid": "#15:2",
        "class": "Currency",
        "Name_currency": "Гривна"
    }
]
```

Comment: Show us your efforts, no one can code for you..

Comment: Is `res.json` a function of some kind?

Comment: @Andy It is part of Express.js callback for request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on your backend (Node.js) site:

```
res.json(record[0].content.map(function(e) {
    return e.value;
}));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried to sort out and rewrite all the new array. Thank you again!)

Answer (score 1):

You should use javascript map() method (where `a` is your first array):

```
var newObj = a.map(function(obj){
    return obj.value;
});

console.log(newObj);
```

For more information https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

use `.each()` in jquery to traverse the object

```
var value=[];
$.each(data,function(i,val){   
  value.push(val.value);  
});

console.log(value);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9sPw6/1/)